# How to convert tensorflow model (say *.pb format) to armnn (*.armnn format)

Tags: tensorflow, converters

I want to convert tensorflow model to armnn. I tried to build armnn from scratch for linux.
I tried this link -> https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/blob/branches/armnn_19_11/BuildGuideCrossCompilation.md but I didn't able to build armnn Converter object file.
Could anybody help me out to build it successfully.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use armnn Converter for the same task. Converter can convert only limited layers
For tenserflow support you can go to below link and explore layers.
https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/blob/branches/armnn_20_08/src/armnnTfParser/TensorFlowSupport.md

Below Url you can get source for armnn converter. You can build it independently
https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/tree/branches/armnn_20_08/src/armnnConverter

For Conversion you can use command like below example

```
ArmnnConverter -f tensorflow-binary -m {pb_filename} -i {input_layers} -o 
{output_layer} -s {input-size} -p {model_name_after_conversion}
```